# React.js - HTML Table nested rows are not correctly rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm facing an issue with rendering the table data. There are a total of four columns and the last two columns can also contain nested rows. But facing a problem rendering this behavior How can I achieve this via the HTML table element in React.js?

**Please see the screenshot as an example:**

[image: Table Prreview]

**Code:**

```
const data = [
  {
    product: "Shirt",
    price: "$20",
    attributes: [
      { type: "Color", value: "Red" },
      { type: "Color", value: "" },
      { type: "Color", value: "Brown" },
    ],
  },
  {
    product: "Shirt 2",
    price: "$25",
    attributes: [
      { type: "Color", value: "Red" },
      { type: "", value: "Yellow" },
      { type: "Color", value: "Brown" },
    ],
  },
  {
    product: "Shirt 3",
    price: "$20",
    attributes: [{ type: "Color", value: "Red" }],
  },
  {
    product: "Shirt 4",
    price: "$30",
    attributes: [],
  },
];

export default function TableComponent() {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div>
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Product</th>
              <th>Price</th>
              <th>Attributes</th>
              <th>Values</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>

          <tbody>
            {data.map((ele, index) => {
              return (
                <tr key={`row-${index}`}>
                  <td>{ele.product}</td>
                  <td>{ele.price}</td>
                  {ele.attributes.map((attr, index) => {
                    return (
                      <Fragment key={`attr-${index}`}>
                        <td>{attr.type}</td>
                        <td>{attr.value}</td>
                      </Fragment>
                    );
                  })}
                </tr>
              );
            })}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `rowspan` attribute on the [td](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td) element. It makes the cell span across multiple table rows. For you case you need to add `td` with `rowspan` in the first row for each "product", and other rows for this product would have first 2 `td` elements omitted.   A working example https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-mendeleev-p8cwx3?file=/src/App.js

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you please also explain how it is working? rowspan

Comment: for better look just add styles  `<table style={{ borderCollapse: "collapse", width: "100%" }}>` and `<th style={{  border: "1px solid black",textAlign: "left"}}>Product</th>`

Comment: @VenNilson expanded the answer, please take a look